# Обернуть в span определенное слово

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Будьте добры подскажите, как с помощью чистого JS обернуть каждый "руб." в тег span (при условии что руб. имеется в данном блоке)?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="value">3775 руб.</div>
    <div class="value">4775 руб.</div>
    <div class="value">5775 руб.</div>
    <div class="value">6775</div>
 </div>
```

```
.value {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000000
}

.value span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так. Находим все элементы, проходим циклом, в цикле с помощью метода replace находим руб. и меняем, на span. Далее с помощью innerHTM заменяем на странице.

```
\.- для справки, экранирую точку, чтобы искалось как точка. Если не экранировать то точка воспринимается как любой символ
```

```js
let text
let value = document.querySelectorAll('.value')
value.forEach(item => {
    text = item.textContent.replace(/руб\./, '<span>руб.</span>')
    item.innerHTML = text
})
```

```css
.value {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000000
}

.value span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="value">3775 руб.</div>
    <div class="value">4775 руб.</div>
    <div class="value">5775 руб.</div>
    <div class="value">6775 руб.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, удачи